# Fluent nhiberante mapping for legacy tables

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping, legacy-database

How to define fluent nhibernate mapping for the Legacy tables.

I have four table

1. CTType(**id** GUID, **Name** varchar(100), **DateOFbirth** datetime)
2. CTType_Legacy(**id** GUID, **CTType_Legacy_id** identity int)
3. CTTypeMap(**id** GUID, **createdOn** datetime, **CtType_id** guid)
4. CTTypeMap_Legacy(**id** GUID, **CT_Type_id** int)

Info

- The first two tables have fixed 50 records. These tables are populated first time when the database is configured for a client.
- For the first two table IDs is mapping column(primary-forign key).
- The last two tables CtType_id is mapped to Id column of CTType table

From the UI when the user saves a new CTTypeMapObject it inserts record into CTTypeMap table. The mapping is defined as:

```
public class CTTypeMapMap :Enity<CTTypeMap>
{
    Public CTTypeMapMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID);
        Map(x => x.createdOn);
        References(x = x.CtType);

        Join("CTTypeMap_Legacy", join =>
        {
            join.KeyColumn("Id");
            join.Map(x => x.CTTypeMap).Column("CT_Type_id");  //not working
        });
    }
}
```

The value for the column **CT_Type_id** of table **CTTypeMap_Legacy** should be **CTType_Legacy_id** column value of **CTType_Legacy**. I am not able to insert the correct value into **CT_Type_id** of table **CTTypeMap_Legacy**.

Could someone please let me know how to do the mapping on the line highlighted with the comment?

Answer (score 0):

it is not clear where you set the value but i guess you mean

```
join.References(x => x.CTType_Legacy).Column("CT_Type_id");
```

Update: the following diables lazy-loading

```
join.References(x => x.CTType).Column("CT_Type_id").PropertyRef("CTType_Legacy_id");
```

or

```
join.Map(x => FakeProperty).Column("CT_Type_id").Access.Using<MyPropertyAccessor>();

// in Igetter
public object Get(object obj)
{
    return ((CTTypeMap)obj).CTType.LegacyId;
}
```

Comment: The table CTType_Legacy and CTTypeMap_Legacy are not defined as entity class in c#,Hence you see the mappind is defined as Join("CTTypeMap_Legacy", join =>) hence the above solution will not work.

Comment: The tables CTType and CTType_legacy are already populated when the database is ran with initilization data set up through scripts.So only the other two tables has to be populated based on user opeartion on UI.Your solution i.e join.References(x => x.CTType).Column("CT_Type_id").PropertyRef("CTType_Legacy_id");doesn't get the CTType_Legacy_id of the table CTType_Legacy that needs to be inserted into CT_Type_id column of CTTypeMap_Legacy table.

Comment: it does assuming you have a referece to the cttype from the database. Othwise thee is still context missing. post the inserting code and what generated sql you expect.